# Dynamic Language Interpreter in C#

Tags: c#, interpreter

This code interprets an abstract syntax tree generated by a recursive descent parser for a dynamic scripting language called Hassium. The syntax of this language looks like this

```
# Recursion functions

func fibonacci(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

func main () {
    for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
        println(fibonacci(i));
    }
}
```

Anyways, people on an IRC network I am a member of have been complaining with this specific class. Obliviously, this a very big file so I wouldn't ask you all to review every line. It works, but what stylistic things should be refactored; such as readability, design, coding style, ect? Also does this reek of anti-patterns or bad code smell?
    // Credit to contributer Zdimension, who has done countless amounts of work on this project

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Hassium.Functions;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Collections;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Conversion;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Debug;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Drawing;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.IO;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Math;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Networking;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Networking.HTTP;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Text;
using Hassium.HassiumObjects.Types;
using Hassium.Lexer;
using Hassium.Parser;
using Hassium.Parser.Ast;
using Hassium.Semantics;

namespace Hassium.Interpreter
{
    public delegate void ExitEventHandler(int code);

    /// <summary>
    /// Interpreter.
    /// </summary>
    public class Interpreter : IVisitor
    {
        public Stack<StackFrame> CallStack = new Stack<StackFrame>();
        public Dictionary<string, HassiumObject> Globals = new Dictionary<string, HassiumObject>();

        public AstNode Code { get; set; }
        public SymbolTable SymbolTable { get; set; }

        public int isInFunction;

        private bool enforceMainEntryPoint;
        private bool isRepl;
        private bool firstExecute = true;

        private int isInLoop;
        private bool continueLoop;
        private bool breakLoop;
        public bool returnFunc;

        public HassiumObject GetVariable(string name, AstNode node)
        {
            if (Constants.ContainsKey(name))
                return Constants[name];
            if (CallStack.Count > 0 && CallStack.Any(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name)))
                return CallStack.First(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name)).Locals[name];
            if (CallStack.Count > 0 && CallStack.Any(x => x.Locals.Any(y => y.Key.StartsWith(name))))
                return
                    CallStack.First(x => x.Locals.Any(y => y.Key.StartsWith(name)))
                        .Locals.First(x => x.Key.StartsWith(name))
                        .Value;
            if (Globals.ContainsKey(name))
                return Globals[name];
            if (Globals.Any(x => x.Key.StartsWith(name)))
                return Globals.First(x => x.Key.StartsWith(name)).Value;

            else throw new ParseException("The variable '" + name + "' doesn't exist.", node);
        }

        public bool HasVariable(string name, bool onlyglobal = false)
        {
            return onlyglobal
                ? Globals.ContainsKey(name) || Constants.ContainsKey(name)
                : Globals.ContainsKey(name) || Constants.ContainsKey(name) ||
                  (CallStack.Count > 0 &&
                   (CallStack.Peek().Scope.Symbols.Contains(name) || CallStack.Any(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name))));
        }

        public void SetVariable(string name, HassiumObject value, AstNode node, bool forceglobal = false,
            bool onlyexist = false)
        {
            if (Constants.ContainsKey(name))
                throw new ParseException("Can't change the value of the internal constant '" + name + "'.", node);

            if (!forceglobal && CallStack.Count > 0 &&
                (!onlyexist ||
                 (CallStack.Peek().Scope.Symbols.Contains(name) || CallStack.Any(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name)))) &&
                !Globals.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                if (CallStack.Any(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name)))
                    CallStack.First(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name)).Locals[name] = value;
                else CallStack.Peek().Locals[name] = value;
            }
            else
                Globals[name] = value;
        }

        public void FreeVariable(string name, AstNode node, bool forceglobal = false)
        {
            if (Constants.ContainsKey(name))
                throw new ParseException("Can't delete internal constant '" + name + "'.", node);
            if (forceglobal)
            {
                if (!Globals.ContainsKey(name))
                    throw new ParseException("The global variable '" + name + "' doesn't exist.", node);
                Globals.Remove(name);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!HasVariable(name)) throw new ParseException("The variable '" + name + "' doesn't exist.", node);
                if (CallStack.Count > 0 &&
                    (CallStack.Peek().Scope.Symbols.Contains(name) || CallStack.Any(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name))))
                    CallStack.First(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name) || x.Scope.Symbols.Contains(name))
                        .Locals.Remove(name);
                else
                    Globals.Remove(name);
            }
        }

        public bool HasFunction(string name, int parm, AstNode node)
        {
            return HasVariable(name + "`" + parm) || HasVariable(name + "`i") || HasVariable(name);
        }

        public IFunction GetFunction(string name, int parm, AstNode node)
        {
            if (HasVariable(name + "`" + parm))
            {
                return GetVariable(name + "`" + parm, node);
            }
            if (HasVariable(name + "`i"))
            {
                return GetVariable(name + "`i", node);
            }
            if (HasVariable(name))
            {
                return GetVariable(name, node);
            }
            throw new ParseException("The function " + name + " doesn't exist", node);
        }

        private bool exit;
        public int exitcode = -1;

        public Dictionary<string, HassiumObject> Constants = new Dictionary<string, HassiumObject>
        {
            {"true", new HassiumBool(true)},
            {"false", new HassiumBool(false)},
            {"Convert", new HassiumConvert()},
            {"Console", new HassiumConsole()},
            {"null", null},
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Interpreter"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public Interpreter(bool forcemain = true)
        {
            SymbolTable = new SymbolTable();
            enforceMainEntryPoint = forcemain;
            LoadInternalFunctions();
        }

        public Interpreter(SymbolTable symbolTable, AstNode code, bool forcemain = true)
        {
            Code = code;
            SymbolTable = symbolTable;
            enforceMainEntryPoint = forcemain;
            LoadInternalFunctions();
        }

        public void Execute(bool repl = false)
        {
            isRepl = repl;
            foreach (var node in Code.Children)
            {
                if (node is FuncNode && firstExecute)
                {
                    var fnode = ((FuncNode) node);
                    var scope = SymbolTable.ChildScopes[fnode.Name + "`" + fnode.Parameters.Count];
                    SetVariable(fnode.Name + "`" + fnode.Parameters.Count, new HassiumMethod(this, fnode, scope, null),
                        node);
                }
                else if (node is ClassNode)
                {
                    var cnode = ((ClassNode) node);
                    if (!Globals.ContainsKey(cnode.Name))
                        Globals.Add(cnode.Name, new HassiumClass(cnode, this));
                }
            }

            if (!Globals.ContainsKey("main`0") && enforceMainEntryPoint)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not execute, no main entry point of program!");
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }

            firstExecute = false;
            foreach (var node in Code.Children)
            {
                if (exit) return;
                if (node is FuncNode)
                {
                    var fnode = ((FuncNode) node);
                    var scope = SymbolTable.ChildScopes[fnode.Name + "`" + fnode.Parameters.Count];
                    //If there is a main, let it be the main entry point of the program
                    if (fnode.Name == "main")
                    {
                        new HassiumMethod(this, fnode, scope, null).Invoke();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                    node.Visit(this);
            }
        }

        public void LoadInternalFunctions()
        {
            foreach (var entry in GetFunctions())
                Globals.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }

        private HassiumObject interpretBinaryOp(BinOpNode node)
        {
            var right = (HassiumObject) node.Right.Visit(this);
            if (node.BinOp == BinaryOperation.Assignment)
            {
                if (node.Left is ArrayGetNode)
                {
                    var call = (ArrayGetNode) (node.Left);

                    if (!call.Target.CanBeIndexed)
                        throw new ParseException(
                            "The [] operator only applies to objects of type Array, Dictionary or String.", node);

                    if (!call.Target.CanBeModified)
                        throw new ParseException("The specified target cannot be modified.", node);

                    var evaluated = call.Target.Visit(this);
                    if (evaluated is HassiumDictionary)
                    {
                        var theArray = ((HassiumDictionary) evaluated);
                        HassiumObject arid = null;

                        if (call.Arguments.Children.Count > 0)
                            arid = (HassiumObject) call.Arguments.Children[0].Visit(this);

                        var theValue = (node.IsOpAssign && arid != null)
                            ? interpretBinaryOp(theArray[arid], right, node.AssignOperation)
                            : right;

                        if (arid == null)
                            theArray.Value.Add(new HassiumKeyValuePair(theArray.Value.Count, theValue));
                        else
                        {
                            if (theArray.Value.Any(cur => cur.Key.ToString() == arid.ToString()))
                            {
                                foreach (var cur in theArray.Value.Where(cur => cur.Key.ToString() == arid.ToString()))
                                {
                                    theArray.Value[cur.Key].Key = theValue;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                theArray[arid] = theValue;
                            }
                        }

                        SetVariable(call.Target.ToString(), theArray, call);
                    }
                    else if (evaluated is HassiumArray || evaluated is HassiumString)
                    {
                        HassiumArray theArray = null;
                        if (evaluated is HassiumString)
                        {
                            theArray = new HassiumArray(evaluated.ToString().ToCharArray().Cast<object>());
                        }
                        theArray = ((HassiumArray) evaluated);

                        int arid = -1;
                        bool append = false;

                        if (call.Arguments.Children.Count > 0)
                            arid = (HassiumObject) call.Arguments.Children[0].Visit(this);
                        else
                            append = true;

                        var theValue = node.IsOpAssign
                            ? interpretBinaryOp(theArray[arid], right, node.AssignOperation)
                            : right;

                        if (append)
                            theArray.Add(new[] {theValue});
                        else
                        {
                            if (arid >= theArray.Value.Length)
                                throw new ParseException("The index is out of the bounds of the array", call);

                            theArray[arid] = theValue;
                        }

                        SetVariable(call.Target.ToString(), theArray, call);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ParseException(
                            "The [] operator only applies to objects of type Array, Dictionary or String.", node);
                    }
                }
                else if (node.Left is MemberAccessNode)
                {
                    var accessor = (MemberAccessNode) node.Left;
                    var target = (HassiumObject) accessor.Left.Visit(this);
                    target.SetAttribute(accessor.Member, right);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!(node.Left is IdentifierNode))
                        throw new ParseException("Not a valid identifier", node);
                    SetVariable(node.Left.ToString(),
                        node.IsOpAssign
                            ? interpretBinaryOp(new BinOpNode(node.Position, node.AssignOperation, node.Left, node.Right))
                            : right, node);
                }
                return right;
            }
            var left = node.Left.Visit(this);
            if (node.BinOp == BinaryOperation.Is)
            {
                var target = right;
                Type ttype = null;
                if (target is HassiumClass) ttype = target.GetType();
                return left.GetType() == ttype;
            }
            return interpretBinaryOp(left, right, node.IsOpAssign ? node.AssignOperation : node.BinOp, node.Position);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Interprets a binary op
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="left">The left-hand parameter</param>
        /// <param name="right">The right-hand parameter</param>
        /// <param name="_op">The operation type</param>
        /// <param name="pos">position</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the operation</returns>
        private HassiumObject interpretBinaryOp(object left, object right, BinaryOperation _op, int pos = -1)
        {
            if (left == null && _op != BinaryOperation.NullCoalescing)
                throw new ParseException("Left operand can't be null", pos);
            if (left is AstNode) left = ((AstNode) left).Visit(this);
            if (left is int) left = (double) (int) left;
            if (right is AstNode) right = ((AstNode) right).Visit(this);
            if (right is int) right = (double) (int) right;
            switch (_op)
            {
                case BinaryOperation.Addition:
                    if (left is HassiumString || right is HassiumString)
                        return new HassiumString(left + right.ToString());
                    if (left is HassiumDate || right is HassiumDate)
                        return (HassiumDate) left + (HassiumDate) right;
                    if (left is HassiumKeyValuePair || right is HassiumKeyValuePair)
                        return new HassiumString(left + right.ToString());
                    if (left is HassiumInt && right is HassiumInt)
                        return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) + Convert.ToInt32(right));
                    if (left is HassiumEvent && right is HassiumMethod)
                    {
                        var ev = (HassiumEvent) left;
                        ev.AddHandler((HassiumMethod) right);
                        return ev;
                    }
                    return new HassiumDouble(Convert.ToDouble(left) + Convert.ToDouble(right));
                case BinaryOperation.Subtraction:
                    if (left is HassiumInt && right is HassiumInt)
                        return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) - Convert.ToInt32(right));
                    if (left is HassiumEvent && right is HassiumMethod)
                    {
                        var ev = (HassiumEvent) left;
                        ev.RemoveHandler((HassiumMethod) right);
                        return ev;
                    }
                    return new HassiumDouble(Convert.ToDouble(left) - Convert.ToDouble(right));
                case BinaryOperation.Division:
                    if (Convert.ToDouble(right) == 0.0) throw new ParseException("Cannot divide by zero", pos);
                    if (left is HassiumInt && right is HassiumInt)
                        return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) / Convert.ToInt32(right));
                    return new HassiumDouble(Convert.ToDouble(left) / Convert.ToDouble(right));
                case BinaryOperation.Multiplication:
                    if ((left is HassiumString && right is HassiumInt) ||
                        right is HassiumString && left is HassiumInt)
                    {
                        if (left is HassiumString)
                            return new HassiumString(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(left, Convert.ToInt32(right))));
                        else
                            return new HassiumString(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(right, Convert.ToInt32(left))));
                    }
                    if (left is HassiumInt && right is HassiumInt)
                        return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) * Convert.ToInt32(right));
                    return new HassiumDouble(Convert.ToDouble(left) * Convert.ToDouble(right));
                case BinaryOperation.Equals:
                    return new HassiumBool(left.ToString() == right.ToString());
                case BinaryOperation.LogicalAnd:
                    return new HassiumBool(Convert.ToBoolean(left) && Convert.ToBoolean(right));
                case BinaryOperation.LogicalOr:
                    return new HassiumBool(Convert.ToBoolean(left) || Convert.ToBoolean(right));
                case BinaryOperation.NotEqualTo:
                    return new HassiumBool(left.GetHashCode() != right.GetHashCode());
                case BinaryOperation.LessThan:
                    return new HassiumBool(Convert.ToDouble(left) < Convert.ToDouble(right));
                case BinaryOperation.GreaterThan:
                    return new HassiumBool(Convert.ToDouble(left) > Convert.ToDouble(right));
                case BinaryOperation.GreaterOrEqual:
                    return new HassiumBool(Convert.ToDouble(left) >= Convert.ToDouble(right));
                case BinaryOperation.LesserOrEqual:
                    return new HassiumBool(Convert.ToDouble(left) <= Convert.ToDouble(right));
                case BinaryOperation.CombinedComparison:
                    if (new HassiumBool(interpretBinaryOp(left, right, BinaryOperation.GreaterThan)))
                        return new HassiumInt(1);
                    return new HassiumBool(interpretBinaryOp(left, right, BinaryOperation.LessThan))
                        ? new HassiumInt(-1)
                        : new HassiumInt(0);
                case BinaryOperation.Xor:
                    return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) ^ Convert.ToInt32(right));
                case BinaryOperation.BitwiseAnd:
                    return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) & Convert.ToInt32(right));
                case BinaryOperation.BitwiseOr:
                    return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) | Convert.ToInt32(right));
                case BinaryOperation.BitshiftLeft:
                    return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) << Convert.ToInt32(right));
                case BinaryOperation.BitshiftRight:
                    return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) >> Convert.ToInt32(right));
                case BinaryOperation.Modulus:
                    return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(left) % Convert.ToInt32(right));

                case BinaryOperation.Pow:
                    if (left is HassiumInt && right is HassiumInt)
                        return new HassiumInt((int) Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(left), Convert.ToInt32(right)));
                    return new HassiumDouble(Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(left), Convert.ToDouble(right)));
                case BinaryOperation.Root:
                    /*if (left is HassiumInt && right is HassiumInt)
                        return new HassiumInt((int)Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(left), 1.0 / Convert.ToDouble(right)));*/
                    return new HassiumDouble(Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(left), 1.0 / Convert.ToDouble(right)));

                case BinaryOperation.NullCoalescing:
                    return HassiumObject.ToHassiumObject(left) ?? HassiumObject.ToHassiumObject(right);
            }
            // Raise error
            return new HassiumInt(-1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Interprets the unary op.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The unary op.</returns>
        /// <param name="node">Node.</param>
        private HassiumObject interpretUnaryOp(UnaryOpNode node)
        {
            var value = node.Value.Visit(this);
            switch (node.UnOp)
            {
                case UnaryOperation.Not:
                    return !Convert.ToBoolean(value);
                case UnaryOperation.Negate:
                    if (value is int) return -(int) value;
                    return -Convert.ToDouble(value);
                case UnaryOperation.Complement:
                    return ~(int) Convert.ToDouble(value);
            }
            //Raise error
            return -1;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the functions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The functions.</returns>
        /// <param name="path">Path.</param>
        public static Dictionary<string, InternalFunction> GetFunctions(string path = "")
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, InternalFunction>();

            var testAss = path == "" ? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() : Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

            foreach (var type in testAss.GetTypes())
            {
                if (type.GetInterface(typeof (ILibrary).FullName) != null)
                {
                    foreach (var myfunc in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
                    {
                        var theattr1 = myfunc.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (IntFunc), true);
                        foreach (var theattr in theattr1.OfType<IntFunc>())
                        {
                            foreach (int argNumber in theattr.Arguments)
                            {
                                var rfunc = new InternalFunction(
                                    (HassiumFunctionDelegate)
                                        Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (HassiumFunctionDelegate), myfunc),
                                    argNumber, false, theattr.Constructor);
                                result.Add(theattr.Name + "`" + (argNumber == -1 ? "i" : argNumber.ToString()), rfunc);
                                if (theattr.Alias != "")
                                    result.Add(theattr.Alias + "`" + (argNumber == -1 ? "i" : argNumber.ToString()), rfunc);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public object Accept(Expression expr)
        {
            VisitSubnodes(expr);
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(ArgListNode node)
        {
            var arguments = new HassiumObject[node.Children.Count];
            for (var x = 0; x < node.Children.Count; x++)
            {
                arguments[x] = (HassiumObject) node.Children[x].Visit(this);
            }
            return arguments;
        }

        public object Accept(ArrayGetNode node)
        {
            var call = node;

            if (!call.Target.CanBeIndexed)
                throw new ParseException(
                    "The [] operator only applies to objects of type Array, Dictionary or String.", node);

            var evaluated = (HassiumObject) call.Target.Visit(this);
            if (evaluated is HassiumDictionary)
            {
                var theArray = ((HassiumDictionary) evaluated);
                HassiumObject arid = null;

                if (call.Arguments.Children.Count > 0)
                    arid = (HassiumObject) call.Arguments.Children[0].Visit(this);

                if (arid == null)
                    return theArray.Value.Last().Value;
                else
                {
                    return theArray.Value.Any(cur => cur.Key.ToString() == arid.ToString())
                        ? theArray.Value.First(cur => cur.Key.ToString() == arid.ToString()).Value
                        : theArray[arid];
                }
            }
            else if (evaluated is HassiumArray || evaluated is HassiumString)
            {
                HassiumArray theArray = null;
                if (evaluated is HassiumString)
                {
                    theArray = new HassiumArray(evaluated.ToString().ToCharArray().Cast<object>());
                }
                else theArray = ((HassiumArray) evaluated);

                int arid = -1;
                bool append = false;

                if (call.Arguments.Children.Count > 0)
                    arid = (HassiumObject) call.Arguments.Children[0].Visit(this);
                else
                    append = true;

                int count = (HassiumObject) call.Count.Visit(this);

                if (append)
                    return theArray.Value.Last();
                else
                {
                    if (arid >= theArray.Value.Length || arid + count > theArray.Value.Length)
                        throw new ParseException("The index is out of the bounds of the array", call);

                    var r = theArray.Value.Skip(arid).Take(count).ToArray();
                    return r.Length == 1 ? r[0] : r.ToArray();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ParseException(
                    "The [] operator only applies to objects of type Array, Dictionary or String.", node);
            }
        }

        public object Accept(ArrayIndexerNode node)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(ArrayInitializerNode node)
        {
            var ainode = node;
            var content = ainode.Value;
            if (ainode.IsDictionary)
                return new HassiumDictionary(content.Select(
                    pair =>
                        new KeyValuePair<HassiumObject, HassiumObject>(
                            pair.Key is AstNode
                                ? (HassiumObject) ((AstNode) (pair.Key)).Visit(this)
                                : HassiumObject.ToHassiumObject(pair.Key),
                            pair.Value is AstNode
                                ? (HassiumObject) ((AstNode) (pair.Value)).Visit(this)
                                : HassiumObject.ToHassiumObject(pair.Value)))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));
            else
                return
                    new HassiumArray(
                        content.Values.Select(x => x is AstNode ? (HassiumObject) ((AstNode) x).Visit(this) : x));
        }

        public object Accept(BinOpNode node)
        {
            var bnode = node;
            var res = interpretBinaryOp(bnode);
            if (isRepl) ConsoleFunctions.PrintLn(new[] {res});
            return res;
        }

        public object Accept(BreakNode node)
        {
            if (isInLoop == 0) throw new ParseException("'break' cannot be used outside a loop", node);
            breakLoop = true;
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(CaseNode node)
        {
            node.Body.Visit(this);
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(ClassNode node)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(CodeBlock node)
        {
            VisitSubnodes(node);
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(ConditionalOpNode node)
        {
            var ifStmt = node;
            if ((HassiumBool) (ifStmt.Predicate.Visit(this)))
            {
                return ifStmt.Body.Visit(this);
            }
            else
            {
                return ifStmt.ElseBody.Visit(this);
            }
        }

        public object Accept(ContinueNode node)
        {
            if (isInLoop == 0) throw new ParseException("'continue' cannot be used outside a loop", node);
            continueLoop = true;
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(ForEachNode node)
        {
            var forStmt = node;
            var needlestmt = forStmt.Needle;
            var haystackstmt = forStmt.Haystack.Visit(this);

            isInLoop++;
            if (haystackstmt is HassiumDictionary)
            {
                var theArray = ((HassiumDictionary) haystackstmt);

                var keyvname = "";
                var valvname = "";
                if (needlestmt is ArrayInitializerNode)
                {
                    keyvname = ((ArrayInitializerNode) needlestmt).Value[0].ToString();
                    valvname = ((ArrayInitializerNode) needlestmt).Value[1].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    valvname = needlestmt.ToString();
                }
                if (keyvname != "") SetVariable(keyvname, null, forStmt);
                SetVariable(valvname, null, forStmt);
                foreach (var needle in (keyvname != "" ? theArray : (IEnumerable) (theArray.Value.Select(x => x.Value)))
                    )
                {
                    if (keyvname != "") SetVariable(keyvname, ((HassiumKeyValuePair) needle).Key, forStmt);
                    SetVariable(valvname,
                        keyvname != "" ? ((HassiumKeyValuePair) needle).Value : HassiumObject.ToHassiumObject(needle),
                        forStmt);
                    forStmt.Body.Visit(this);
                    if (continueLoop) continueLoop = false;
                    if (breakLoop)
                    {
                        breakLoop = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (keyvname != "") FreeVariable(keyvname, forStmt);
                FreeVariable(valvname, forStmt);
                isInLoop--;
            }
            else if (haystackstmt is HassiumArray || haystackstmt is HassiumString)
            {
                HassiumArray theArray = null;
                if (haystackstmt is HassiumString)
                {
                    theArray = new HassiumArray(haystackstmt.ToString().ToCharArray().Cast<object>());
                }
                else theArray = ((HassiumArray) haystackstmt);

                var valvname = needlestmt.ToString();

                SetVariable(valvname, null, forStmt);
                foreach (var needle in theArray.Value)
                {
                    SetVariable(valvname, HassiumObject.ToHassiumObject(needle), forStmt);
                    forStmt.Body.Visit(this);
                    if (continueLoop) continueLoop = false;
                    if (breakLoop)
                    {
                        breakLoop = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                FreeVariable(valvname, forStmt);
                isInLoop--;
            }
            else
            {
                isInLoop--;
                throw new ParseException("Foreach can only be used with objects of type Array, Dictionary or String.",
                    node);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(ForNode node)
        {
            var forStmt = node;
            isInLoop++;
            forStmt.Left.Visit(this);
            while ((HassiumBool) (forStmt.Predicate.Visit(this)))
            {
                forStmt.Body.Visit(this);
                if (continueLoop) continueLoop = false;
                if (breakLoop)
                {
                    breakLoop = false;
                    break;
                }
                forStmt.Right.Visit(this);
            }
            isInLoop--;
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(FuncNode node)
        {
            var fnode = node;
            var stackFrame = new StackFrame(SymbolTable.ChildScopes[fnode.Name + "`" + fnode.Parameters.Count]);
            if (CallStack.Count > 0)
            {
                stackFrame.Scope.Symbols.AddRange(CallStack.Peek().Scope.Symbols);
                CallStack.Peek().Locals.All(x =>
                {
                    stackFrame.Locals.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
                    return true;
                });
            }
            var hfunc = new HassiumMethod(this, fnode, stackFrame, null);
            SetVariable(fnode.Name + "`" + fnode.Parameters.Count, hfunc, fnode);
            return hfunc;
        }


        public object Accept(FunctionCallNode node)
        {
            var call = node;

            IFunction target = null;


            bool dontEval = false;

            switch (call.Target.ToString())
            {
                case "free":
                    dontEval = true;
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    // internal interpreter functions
                    break;
                default:
                    if ((!(call.Target is MemberAccessNode) &&
                         !HasFunction(call.Target.ToString(), call.Arguments.Children.Count, node)))
                    {
                        throw new ParseException("The function " + call.Target + " doesn't exist", node);
                    }
                    if (call.Target is MemberAccessNode)
                    {
                        var man = (MemberAccessNode) call.Target;
                        var targ = (HassiumObject) man.Left.Visit(this);
                        if (targ.Attributes.ContainsKey(man.Member + "`" + call.Arguments.Children.Count))
                        {
                            target = targ.GetAttribute(man.Member + "`" + call.Arguments.Children.Count, node.Position);
                        }
                        else if (targ.Attributes.ContainsKey(man.Member))
                        {
                            target = targ.GetAttribute(man.Member, node.Position);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new ParseException(
                                "The function " + man.Member + " doesn't exist for the object " + man.Left, node);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        target = GetFunction(call.Target.ToString(), call.Arguments.Children.Count, node);
                    break;
            }

            if (HassiumInterpreter.options.Secure)
            {
                var forbidden = new List<string> {"system", "runtimecall", "input"};
                if (forbidden.Contains(call.Target.ToString()))
                {
                    throw new ParseException("The " + call.Target + "() function is disabled for security reasons.",
                        node);
                }
            }


            if (target is InternalFunction && (target as InternalFunction).IsConstructor)
                throw new ParseException("Attempt to run a constructor without the 'new' operator", node);

            if (target is HassiumMethod)
            {
                var th = target as HassiumMethod;
                if (!th.IsStatic)
                {
                    if (call.Target is MemberAccessNode)
                    {
                        var man = (MemberAccessNode) call.Target;
                        if (!((HassiumObject) man.Left.Visit(this)).IsInstance)
                        {
                            throw new ParseException("Non-static method can only be used with instance of class", call);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var arguments = new HassiumObject[call.Arguments.Children.Count];
            for (var x = 0; x < call.Arguments.Children.Count; x++)
            {
                arguments[x] = dontEval
                    ? new HassiumString(call.Arguments.Children[x].ToString())
                    : (HassiumObject) call.Arguments.Children[x].Visit(this);
            }

            switch (call.Target.ToString())
            {
                case "free":
                    FreeVariable(arguments[0].ToString(), node);
                    return null;
                case "exit":
                    exit = true;
                    exitcode = arguments.Length == 0 ? 0 : arguments[0].HInt().Value;
                    return null;
            }


            HassiumObject ret = target.Invoke(arguments);
            if (returnFunc)
                returnFunc = false;
            //if (ret is HassiumArray) ret = ((Array)ret).Cast<HassiumObject>().Select((s, i) => new { s, i }).ToDictionary(x => HassiumObject.ToHassiumObject(x.i), x => HassiumObject.ToHassiumObject(x.s));
            return ret;
        }

        public object Accept(IdentifierNode node)
        {
            return GetVariable(node.Identifier, node);
        }

        public object Accept(IfNode node)
        {
            var ifStmt = node;
            if ((HassiumBool) (ifStmt.Predicate.Visit(this)))
            {
                ifStmt.Body.Visit(this);
            }
            else
            {
                ifStmt.ElseBody.Visit(this);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(InstanceNode node)
        {
            var inode = node;
            var fcall = (FunctionCallNode) inode.Target;
            var arguments = (HassiumObject[]) fcall.Arguments.Visit(this);

            HassiumObject theVar = null;
            if (fcall.Target is MemberAccessNode)
            {
                theVar = (HassiumObject) fcall.Target.Visit(this);
            }
            else theVar = (HassiumObject) GetFunction(fcall.Target.ToString(), fcall.Arguments.Children.Count, node);

            if (theVar is InternalFunction)
            {
                var iFunc = (InternalFunction) theVar;
                if (iFunc.IsConstructor)
                {
                    var ret = iFunc.Invoke(arguments);
                    ret.IsInstance = true;
                    return ret;
                }
            }
            else if (theVar is HassiumClass)
            {
                var iCl = (HassiumClass) theVar;
                if (iCl.Attributes.ContainsKey("new"))
                {
                    var ctor = iCl.GetAttribute("new", fcall.Position);
                    ctor.Invoke(arguments);
                    iCl.IsInstance = true;
                    return iCl;
                }
            }

            throw new ParseException("No constructor found for " + fcall.Target, node);
        }

        public object Accept(LambdaFuncNode node)
        {
            var funcNode = node;
            var stackFrame = new StackFrame(SymbolTable.ChildScopes["lambda_" + funcNode.GetHashCode()]);
            if (CallStack.Count > 0)
            {
                stackFrame.Scope.Symbols.AddRange(CallStack.Peek().Scope.Symbols);
                CallStack.Peek().Locals.All(x =>
                {
                    stackFrame.Locals.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
                    return true;
                });
            }
            return new HassiumMethod(this, (FuncNode) funcNode, stackFrame, null);
        }

        public object Accept(MemberAccessNode node)
        {
            var accessor = node;
            var target = (HassiumObject) accessor.Left.Visit(this);
            var attr = target.GetAttribute(accessor.Member, node.Position + 1);
            if (attr is InternalFunction && ((InternalFunction) attr).IsProperty)
            {
                return ((InternalFunction) attr).Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                return attr;
            }
        }

        public object Accept(MentalNode node)
        {
            var mnode = node;
            if (!HasVariable(mnode.Name))
                throw new ParseException(
                    "The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer", mnode);
            var oldValue = GetVariable(mnode.Name, mnode);
            switch (mnode.OpType)
            {
                case "++":
                    SetVariable(mnode.Name, Convert.ToInt32((object) GetVariable(mnode.Name, mnode)) + 1, mnode);
                    break;
                case "--":
                    SetVariable(mnode.Name, Convert.ToInt32((object) GetVariable(mnode.Name, mnode)) - 1, mnode);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ParseException("Unknown operation " + mnode.OpType, mnode);
            }
            return mnode.IsBefore ? GetVariable(mnode.Name, mnode) : oldValue;
        }

        public object Accept(NumberNode node)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once ConvertIfStatementToReturnStatement
            if (node.IsInt)
            {
                return new HassiumInt(Convert.ToInt32(node.Value));
            }
            return new HassiumDouble(node.Value);
        }

        public object Accept(PropertyNode node)
        {
            var prop = new HassiumProperty(node.Name, x => GetPropVal(node, x[0]), x => SetPropVal(node, x[1], x[0]),
                node.SetNode == null);
            SetVariable(node.Name, prop, node);
            return prop;
        }

        private HassiumObject GetPropVal(PropertyNode node, HassiumObject self)
        {
            var funcnode = new HassiumMethod(this,
                new FuncNode(node.GetNode.Position, "__getprop__" + node.Name + "`1", new List<string> {"this"},
                    node.GetNode.Body), SymbolTable.ChildScopes["__getprop__" + node.Name + "`1"], self);
            return funcnode.Invoke();
        }

        private HassiumObject SetPropVal(PropertyNode node, HassiumObject value, HassiumObject self)
        {
            if (node.SetNode == null)
                throw new ParseException("The property is read-only, it cannot be modified.", node);
            var funcnode = new HassiumMethod(this,
                new FuncNode(node.SetNode.Position, "__setprop__" + node.Name + "`2", new List<string> {"this", "value"},
                    node.SetNode.Body), SymbolTable.ChildScopes["__setprop__" + node.Name + "`2"], self);
            funcnode.Invoke(value);
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(ReturnNode node)
        {
            if (isInFunction == 0) throw new ParseException("'return' cannot be used outside a function", node);
            var returnStmt = node;
            if (returnStmt.Value != null && !returnStmt.Value.ReturnsValue)
                throw new ParseException("This node type doesn't return a value.", returnStmt.Value);
            var ret = returnStmt.Value.Visit(this);
            returnFunc = true;
            CallStack.Peek().ReturnValue = (HassiumObject) ret;
            return ret;
        }

        public object Accept(StatementNode node)
        {
            return node.Visit(this);
        }

        public object Accept(StringNode node)
        {
            return new HassiumString(node.Value);
        }

        public object Accept(SwitchNode node)
        {
            var pred = node.Predicate.Visit(this);
            if (node.Body.Any(x => x.Values.Any(y => y.Visit(this).ToString() == pred.ToString())))
            {
                var cnode = node.Body.First(x => x.Values.Any(y => y.Visit(this).ToString() == pred.ToString()));
                cnode.Visit(this);
            }
            else
            {
                if (node.DefaultBody != null)
                {
                    node.DefaultBody.Visit(this);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(ThreadNode node)
        {
            var threadStmt = node;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => threadStmt.Node.Visit(this));
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(UseNode node)
        {
            if (node.IsModule)
            {
                string mname = node.Path.ToLower();
                if (HassiumInterpreter.options.Secure)
                {
                    var forbidden = new List<string> {"io", "net", "network", "drawing"};
                    if (forbidden.Contains(mname))
                    {
                        throw new ParseException(
                            "The module " + mname + " is cannot be imported for security reasons.", node);
                    }
                }
                switch (mname)
                {
                    case "io":
                        Constants.Add("File", new HassiumFile());
                        Constants.Add("Directory", new HassiumDirectory());
                        Constants.Add("Path", new HassiumPath());
                        Constants.Add("IO", new HassiumIO());
                        Constants.Add("StreamWriter",
                            new InternalFunction(
                                x =>
                                    new HassiumStreamWriter(x[0] is HassiumStream
                                        ? new StreamWriter(((HassiumStream) x[0]).Value)
                                        : new StreamWriter(x[0].ToString())), 1, false, true));
                        Constants.Add("StreamReader",
                            new InternalFunction(
                                x =>
                                    new HassiumStreamReader(x[0] is HassiumStream
                                        ? new StreamReader(((HassiumStream) x[0]).Value)
                                        : new StreamReader(x[0].ToString())), 1, false, true));
                        Constants.Add("FileStream",
                            new InternalFunction(
                                x => new HassiumFileStream(new FileStream(x[0].ToString(), FileMode.OpenOrCreate)), 1,
                                false, true));
                        Constants.Add("BinaryWriter",
                            new InternalFunction(
                                x => new HassiumBinaryWriter(new BinaryWriter(((HassiumStream) x[0]).Value)), 1, false,
                                true));
                        Constants.Add("BinaryReader",
                            new InternalFunction(
                                x => new HassiumBinaryReader(new BinaryReader(((HassiumStream) x[0]).Value)), 1, false,
                                true));
                        break;
                    case "math":
                        Constants.Add("Math", new HassiumMath());
                        break;
                    case "debug":
                        Constants.Add("Debug", new HassiumDebug());
                        break;
                    case "collections":
                        Constants.Add("Stack",
                            new InternalFunction(
                                x =>
                                    new HassiumStack(x.Length == 0
                                        ? new Stack<HassiumObject>()
                                        : new Stack<HassiumObject>(x[0].HInt().Value)), new[] {0, 1}, false, true));
                        Constants.Add("Dictionary",
                            new InternalFunction(
                                x => new HassiumDictionary(new Dictionary<HassiumObject, HassiumObject>()), 0, false,
                                true));
                        break;
                    case "net":
                    case "network":
                        Constants.Add("WebClient",
                            new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumWebClient(new WebClient()), 0, false, true));
                        Constants.Add("TcpClient",
                            new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumTcpClient(new TcpClient()), 0, false, true));
                        Constants.Add("NetworkStream",
                            new InternalFunction(
                                x => new HassiumNetworkStream(new NetworkStream(((HassiumSocket) x[0]).Value)), 1, false,
                                true));
                        Constants.Add("HttpListener",
                            new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumHttpListener(new HttpListener()), 0, false, true));
                        break;
                    case "text":
                        Constants.Add("StringBuilder",
                            new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumStringBuilder(new StringBuilder()), 0, false, true));
                        Constants.Add("Encoding",
                            new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumEncoding(x[0].HString()), 1, false, true));
                        if (!HassiumInterpreter.options.Secure)
                        {
                            Constants.Add("TextWriter",
                                new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumTextWriter(File.CreateText(x[0].ToString())), 1,
                                    false, true));
                            Constants.Add("TextReader",
                                new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumTextReader(File.OpenText(x[0].ToString())), 1,
                                    false, true));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "drawing":
                        Constants.Add("Color",
                            new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumColor(x), new[] {1, 3, 4, 5}, false, true));
                        Constants.Add("Bitmap",
                            new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumBitmap(x), new[] {1, 2}, false, true));
                        Constants.Add("Image",
                            new InternalFunction(x => new HassiumImage(x[0].HString()), 1, false, true));
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Unknown Module: " + node.Path);
                }
            }
            else if (node.IsLibrary)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, InternalFunction> entry in GetFunctions(node.Path))
                    Globals.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Interpreter inter = new Interpreter(false);

                Parser.Parser hassiumParser = new Parser.Parser(new Lexer.Lexer(File.ReadAllText(node.Path)).Tokenize());
                AstNode ast = hassiumParser.Parse();
                inter.SymbolTable = new SemanticAnalyser(ast).Analyse();
                inter.Code = ast;
                inter.Execute();

                if (node.Global)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, HassiumObject> entry in inter.Globals)
                    {
                        if (Globals.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
                            Globals.Remove(entry.Key);
                        Globals.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var modu = new HassiumModule(node.Name);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, HassiumObject> entry in inter.Globals)
                    {
                        modu.SetAttribute(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                    }
                    SetVariable(node.Name, modu, node);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(TryNode node)
        {
            var tryStmt = node;
            try
            {
                tryStmt.Body.Visit(this);
            }
            catch
            {
                tryStmt.CatchBody.Visit(this);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (tryStmt.FinallyBody != null)
                    tryStmt.FinallyBody.Visit(this);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(UnaryOpNode node)
        {
            return interpretUnaryOp(node);
        }

        public object Accept(UncheckedNode node)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                node.Node.Visit(this);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(WhileNode node)
        {
            var whileStmt = node;
            isInLoop++;
            int counter = 0;
            while ((HassiumBool) whileStmt.Predicate.Visit(this))
            {
                counter++;
                whileStmt.Body.Visit(this);
                if (continueLoop) continueLoop = false;
                if (breakLoop)
                {
                    breakLoop = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (counter == 0)
            {
                if (whileStmt.ElseBody != null)
                    whileStmt.ElseBody.Visit(this);
            }
            isInLoop--;
            return null;
        }

        public object Accept(DoNode node)
        {
            var doStmt = node;
            isInLoop++;
            do
            {
                doStmt.DoBody.Visit(this);
                if (continueLoop)
                    continueLoop = false;
                if (breakLoop)
                {
                    breakLoop = false;
                    break;
                }
            } while ((HassiumBool)doStmt.Predicate.Visit(this));

            isInLoop--;
            return null;
        }

        private void VisitSubnodes(AstNode node)
        {
            foreach (var nd in node.Children)
            {
                nd.Visit(this);
                if (continueLoop || breakLoop || returnFunc || exit) break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the project? http://hassiumlang.com/

Comment: I don't really have time at the moment to perform a proper review, but let's say that I wanted to implement a compiler instead of an interpreter. I would have to copy a lot of logic from the `Interpreter` class into my new `Compiler` class. This tells me that there's a missing abstraction and class here to be extracted. I'm just not sure what it is yet. I also have the feeling that a `CallStack` class extending `Stack<StackFrame>` is missing from the implementation. There are a lot of repeated lambda expressions related to that member.

Comment: `public IFunction GetFunction(...)` Implies `HasmiumObject` directly implements `IFunction`. Consider instead a `public class HassiumFunction : HassiumObject, IFunction`

Answer (score 7):

Well, it's a large chunk of code so here just a few things which came to mind when skimming over it:

1. You don't have any unit tests (at least none that I could find on github). You should start writing them. I suspect it will be a PITA to do so which is good since it will highlight refactoring targets plus it will provide regression tests for when you break things while refactoring. Yes it means you'll have to invest time in it without making actual progress on features but if you'd like the project to grow and more people contributing to it you can easily put yourself into a world of pain if you don't.
2. Check all your `public`/`private` modifiers and make sure that only things which need to be `public` actually are. In large blobs like these I often find public methods or properties which aren't used anywhere outside of the class (or not even there). Anything public is a lot harder to change since it will potentially affect a lot of calling code. Things which are private can be changed around at will (as long as you don't break anything, see unit testing above).
3. There is no documentation on the public interface of the class so you are pretty much resigned to read the code if you want to use it.
4. Related to this: The public interface of this class is very broad and it's absolutely not obvious how it is meant to be used. I assume methods are meant to be called in a certain order and in certain states or otherwise things will go wrong. Also having a public dictionary called `Constants` which is apparently everything but constant seems like an oxymoron to me.
5. I tend to start refactoring these kind of things in baby steps. A good candidate seems to the be `CallStack`. Code like this:

   > ```
   > if (CallStack.Count > 0 &&
   >       (CallStack.Peek().Scope.Symbols.Contains(name) || CallStack.Any(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name))))
   >        CallStack.First(x => x.Locals.ContainsKey(name) || x.Scope.Symbols.Contains(name))
   >                 .Locals.Remove(name);
   > ```

   makes things very hard to read and is scattered around in various places. Create a `Callstack` class, define the interface to it in terms of how the Interpreter should interact with it on the most basic level. This should clean up some code.
6. I'm not 100% sure what exactly the purpose of the `Accept` methods is and how they are related to the `interpret*` methods and how it is all related to `Execute`. So at the first glance it seems your `Interpreter` has at least two responsibilities: Turn the AST nodes into `Hassium*` nodes and execute the `Hassium*` nodes. This is at least one responsibility too much and turning the AST nodes into `Hassium*` nodes should probably be extracted.
7. Also reading a lot of code like `if (evaluated is HassiumArray || evaluated is HassiumString)` seems like a step backwards in the age of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

other than above answer my suggestions are

make the code clean by introducing concept into modules had to analysis.

->prevent buffer overflows in ast .

->if it is a interpreted language then why should main is used.

-->would you have any semantic checking modules or code optimizing modules ?

--> you can implement symbol tab which can store class objects or custom data types created by the user so that pointer to the functions can be stored on them.so that on
recursive calls you get its advantages.become more faster.

-->you can implement typecasting. and exception handling in this module